# python stock price using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get the price of the stock using the below code, it returns null for the current price. Please let me know where I am making a error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MMM/key-statistics?p=MMM'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup =soup(page_html,"lxml")
uClient.close()

# I tried this option 1

currentPrice = page_soup.find('div',attrs={"span": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"})
print(currentPrice)

# I tried this option 2

for currentPrice in  page_soup.find("div",{"class": "D(ib) Mend(20px)"})  :   
    print (page_soup.span)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at yfinance
https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/